# How to load html using jQuery load() function from the anchor inside the container itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can actually execute the load() function by clicking the link inside the container that load function load new html page?
In the code below, first I have successfully get the new.html page into container div.

```
<div id="container">
    <ul> 
        <li><a id="t1" href="#">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a id="t2" href="#">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a id="t3" href="#">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>

        ...Some html data here.... 
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#t1").click(function(){
        $( "#container" ).load( "tab1.html" );
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#t1").click(function(){
        $( "#container" ).load( "tab2.html" );
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#t1").click(function(){
        $( "#container" ).load( "tab3.html" );
    });
});
```

here tab1.html, tab2.html and tab3.html will also contain the same tab navigation list with same id but with different data.

```
    <ul> 
        <li><a id="t1" href="#">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a id="t2" href="#">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a id="t3" href="#">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
   ...different data here.....
```

Now, whenever if first execute the page, at first time I can easy load any one of three page (tab1 or tab2 or tab3). However, after loading these page, I cannot load another page. For instance, after loading tab2, which will also contain tab navigation with same id, I am unable to navigate to tab 1 or tab3.

So, anyone please tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: first off, `id should always be unique`

Comment: The content inside the div "container" will be completely replaced after calling the load() function. So, I believe that there should not be any unique id violation.

Comment: can you make a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: I would guess that the binding of the JS functions to the click event of the list items happens only once after the very first load of the page. Therefore, even given that you replace the list items with new ones having the same IDs, they won't have the JS code bound to their click event since the jQuery code does not execute.

Comment: Are you loading any dynamic content on tabs??

Comment: So, @HristoIliev any idea for how can I achieve this or anyway to re-bound the click event or anyway to execute the jQuery code back again?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola, yes. I am loading some data from the database according to option selected from tab. It is possible not include tab section inside the container and load data but I also want to make some CSS change to tab. For instance, when tab2 is loaded, I want to highlight the tab2 and make tab1 and tab3 non-highlight.

Comment: I think the best option here is to use **jquery plugins for tabs** which includes lot of things that you required to handle manually in this case.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola, thanks for the idea.

Comment: It's ok.. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
Thanks guys for your comments and ideas. However, I happen to figure out one solution and which seem to work perfectly for my case. Thanks to @HristoIliev for pointing out about re-validating the jQuery load() function. What I did is I simply add the jQuery load() function snipset to the fragment htmls i.e. (tab1.html, tab2.html and tab3.html).
For example:

```
tab1.html
<ul> 
        <li><a id="t1" href="#">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a id="t2" href="#">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a id="t3" href="#">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
   ...different data here.....

...added jQuery load funciton and which will again revalidate the jQuery code when this fragment html is loaded in the main div "container".
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#t2").click(function(){
        $( "#container" ).load( "tab1.html" );
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#t3").click(function(){
        $( "#container" ).load( "tab1.html" );
    });
});
```

And now its working.!!!